# Add counter jquery

Tags: javascript

I have problem because I don't know how to change code to add counter in name input. So when I will click #add_input new input will have name name[0], name[1] etc.

```
  $("#add_input").click(function () {
var html = '';
html += '<div class="row">';
html += '<input type="checkbox" name="name[0]">';
html += '</div></div>';
};
```

Comment: `cnt =0; cnt++;`

Comment: **name="name[]"** will make the index dynamic

Comment: You HTMl is invalid too. Why not post some more, like where are you adding this? Also if you need to add this to some container, just add the string: `$("#someContainer").append(\`<div class="row"><input type="checkbox" name="name[{cnt++}]"></div>\`)`

Comment: this is my all code

  $("#add_input").click(function () {
 var html = '';
 html += '<div class="row">';
 html += '<input type="checkbox" name="name[0]">';
 html += '</div></div>';
 };
 $('.more').append(html);
 
 $(document).on('click', '#remove_row', function () {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
 });
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let i = 0
$("#add_input").click(() => {
  i += 1;
  var html = `<div class="row">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="name[]"> input ${i}</label>
                  </div>`;

  $('#result').append(html);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_input">add input</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You code doesn't add count to name

Comment: I know, why I should add a counter to the name, adding the counter has no effect

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;

  $("#add_input").click(function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="row">';
    html += '<input type="checkbox" name="name_' + counter + '"/>';
    html += '</div>';

    counter ++;
};
```

Comment: having a number as the first letter in an input field name is generally bad practice

Comment: @Sarout, Is this fine?

Comment: Yes great, thank you for help :)

Comment: yes it works good, but still need edits for being the best answer

Comment: @ldybiec if this solves your issue, please mark it as accepted, so other users know that this is the solution :)

Comment: I think @ldybiec can do the edits now :D

Comment: @Sarout, please go on Sir :D

Comment: @Paveloosha I have edit addiction, I have too many pinned edits, please do what I'll say in the next comment

Comment: add the HTML inside backticks '` `', and copy&paste the HTML inside 1 var, and its preffered to write `counter += 1` inplace of `counter++`

Comment: @Sarout, good habit :) . Are you asking to use template literals (`name_${counter}`)? If so, how could you know "ldybiec" is using ES-6 or not? And, please let me know the benifits of using "counter + = 1" instead of counter ++.

Comment: all browsers using ES6, he can't use the older version, but I don't know how to say it, I forgot why is `count += 1` is better than `count++`  :.) but I think that is faster or something...

Comment: yeah, `for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++);` took *`1313.911376953125 ms`*, and `for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i+=1);` took *`1283.2890625 ms`*. to check use `console.time`